# SQL Sum of String Occurrences with Group By

Tags: mysql, sql

*I have a table called **battery_data**,*

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|Module |Machine| Num1 |  Num3 | Field | Value | Value2 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| T-01  |  A&B  |   23.9|  123  |   Cell|  POS  | 328.34|
| T-01  |  A&B  |   27.0|  456  |Battery|  POS  |   23.8|
| T-01  |  C&D  | 409.01|  789  | EV    |  NEG  | NULL  |
| T-01  |  C&D  | 411.02|  124  | Cell  |  VSB  | NULL  |
| T-02  |  A&B  | 509.01|  989  | EV    |  NEG  | NULL  |
| T-02  |  A&B  | 611.02|  824  |Battery|  VSB  | NULL  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I want an output which returns the occurrences of all **POS/NEG/VSB** in **Value** field aggregated per *unique module and unique machine*. (There are only 2 types of machine: A&B, C&D)

If a certain Value(POS/NEG/VSB) isn't found for a module, 0 should be returned for that column.

*I want to generate an output table as,*

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|Module |Machine|  POS  |  NEG  |  VSB  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  T-01 |  A&B  |   2   |  0    |   0   | 
|  T-01 |  C&D  |   0   |  1    |   1   | 
|  T-02 |  A&B  |   0   |  1    |   1   |   
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

What should be the SQL query to achieve this?

Comment: Which database are you using? You tagged 4 different ones.

Comment: i am using mysql

Comment: You need *conditional aggregation* with `GROUP BY`.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/212260/pivot-values-to-columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, as you say, you want to find "the occurrences of all POS/NEG/VSB in Value field aggregated per unique module and unique machine". So first, you have to group by module and machine, and then for each row you have to count if it's value is POS or NEG or VSB. One way to do that is to have a different counter for every possible value, and then increase the counter that corresponds to the value of the current row. One way of doing that is the following:

```
SELECT Module, Machine,
SUM(CASE WHEN Value = 'POS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS POS,
SUM(CASE WHEN Value = 'NEG' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NEG,
SUM(CASE WHEN Value = 'VSB' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS VSB
FROM battery_data
GROUP BY Module, Machine
```

Comment: [Is "try this" bad practice?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196187/172661) *Try this* is not an answer, and just dumping code does not share any knowledge. Instead of *try this*, write an answer that explains how this solves the problem and how it works, so that this poster (and future readers here) actually learn something from it that they can apply later when they encounter new problems.

Comment: @KenWhite thanks a lot ! I appreciate your feedback, I'm newbie on answering questions in SO, and I want to help, so I will put this on practise.

Comment: There's an [edit] link below your answer. You can start now. :-)